# Why is this microtask executed before macrotask in event loop?

Tags: javascript, browser, timer, task-queue, event-loop

My understanding is that the full microtask task queue is processed *after* each macrotask.

If that is the case, why does the `setTimeout` callback get executed after the `Promise` microtasks in the following snippet of `JavaScript`?

```
console.log('start');

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("setTimeout");
});

Promise.resolve().then(function() {
  console.log('promise');
});

console.log('end');
```

This outputs the following:

```
> "start"
> "end"
> "promise"
> "setTimeout"
```

Is it because of a ~`4ms` delay imposed by modern browsers?

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting):

> In modern browsers, `setTimeout()`/`setInterval()` calls are throttled to
>   a minimum of once every 4ms when successive calls are triggered due to
>   callback nesting (where the nesting level is at least a certain
>   depth), or after certain number of successive intervals.

Though this states that it is only true for successive callback nesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My understanding is that the full microtask task queue is processed after each macrotask.

Yes. And the code that you ran, from `console.log('start')` to `console.log('end')`, *is* such a macrotask. After it ran to completion, the microtask queue with the promise callbacks is processed, and only after that the next macrotask (the timeout) gets to run.