# microtask queue and callback queue in javascript

Tags: javascript, event-loop

The javascript runtime environment has an event loop, callback queue, and microtask queue. The functions in the microtask queue get priority over the functions in the callback queue (for getting pushed into the call stack).

Functions returned from the web API like fetch (which returns a promise) get pushed to the microtask queue while functions returned from web APIs as setTimeout gets pushed to the callback queue. So functions returned by the fetch promise will get executed before the setTimeout.

My doubt is, the console is also a web API, right?? now if we simply want the console to log something then the console web API will return the result which technically should first get stored in the callback queue.

So here we can observe that a simple console log should get lower priority than a fetch (since the returned function from fetch gets stored in the microtask queue while the console is stored in the callback queue.).

So theoretically a function returned from fetch should get executed before a simple console log but in reality, the result is reversed. So what am I missing? Please someone clear my doubt please.

Comment: `console.log` doesn't use microtasks or callbacks...

Comment: Please watch the holy grail of explaining the event loop by Jake Archibald: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0&vl=en

Comment: Okay, I'll watch @caTS

Comment: just a quick question. I found the console uses a macrotask queue but again I found the microtask queue gets priority over the macro task. So my doubt remains the same :(

Comment: No. `console` does not queue any microtasks. If you are referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52019729/why-is-this-microtask-executed-before-macrotask-in-event-loop) question, I understand how you could get that mixed up. What they mean is that the `setTimeout` has queued a macrotask, and that macrotask is the `console.log`.

Comment: Note that although fetch returns a promise it behaves similarly to setTimeout, except that instead of being queued after a timer expires, the promise resolution will be queued after the network response is received.

Comment: I don't get why you got a doubt with the `console` alongside microtask if all the `console` do if just push messages to devtools.

Comment: @Xion14 I got doubt with the console because I'm thinking, the console is also a web API so the result returned from it should also get stored in the callback queue first and when the event loop will find call stack is empty then the event loop will push it to the call stack but it will get lower priority than the functions in the microtask queue like fetch

Comment: @Xion14 in simple words why would the console get priority over fetch web API while fetch is stored in the microtask queue and we know the microtask queue gets priority?

Comment: If with 'Web API' you mean the apis that browsers provide, then not all web apis use these queues. There's no callbacks/events/promises involved. console.log happens immediately.

Comment: The `console API` is `sync`. It is like any function.
While `setTimeout` is async (after sometime it will run the callback) and `queueMicroTask` execute code after all sync code have been executed.

Comment: Yes, I mean the APIs that browsers provide and I'm comparing console webAPI to fetch webAPI @Evert

Comment: @NishantKumar I understand, but not all of these APIs are asynchronous and use queues. Most things *do not*.

Comment: @Evert your answer feels soothing and is giving me some peace but could you please provide me a link or something I want to study in detail about which webAPIs don't wait in callback queues?

Comment: You're even calling it 'callback queues'. This should give you a good hint. There's no callback in `console.log`

Comment: @Evert thanks for this special hint, it seems something is clicking in my mind now, you gave me a new perspective to think. I'll think more deeply about it.

Comment: @NishantKumar Web APIs that are synchronous do not use the event queues. Web APIs that are asynchronous (cause events to be fired later, or are listening to events) do use the event queues.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi. Seems helpful to understand now.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this snippet

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log('ASYNC'))
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('PROMISE')) // also microtask
queueMicrotask(() => console.log('MICROTASK'))
console.log('SYNC')
```

Comment: Yes, perfect but I'm thinking why won't SYNC get logged after PROMISE and MICROTASK because functions in the microtask queue get priority over the callback queue(console waits in callback queue)

Comment: @NishantKumar No, the point of microtask is to execute after all the `sync` code.
This is the reason of the order of the `console.log`.
And in this case the only part that is `sync` is the last `console.log` that is not wrap in any function.

Comment: @NishantKumar There is no "callback queue", and `console.log` does not wait for anything